# Encrypt password in configuration file in Grails 3

Tags: jasypt, grails3

Anybody is using jasypt encryption before? to encrypt password for mail in application.groovy Grails 3.

I'm confused how to encrypt the password in the configuration file, this is what I did and it's not working.

```
environments {
development {
    grails {
        mail {
            host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            port = 465
            username = "xxxxx@xxxxxx"
            password = jasypt
            props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]

        }
    }
}
production {
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
}
```

}

and

```
jasypt {
algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
providerName = "BC"
password = "yizhen2009"
keyObtentionIterations = 1000 }
```

Both codes are in the same file.